What's difference between using get or computed to get value? Why does using get function cause the view to crash?
I'm using shadcn-vue DataTable component on my page.
When I click the button to update the data, the view takes increasingly longer to update. After click about 8 times, then the page crashed.
This is what I see on devtool performance.

The data object from API contains only two objects, so the data is not extensive.
Then I tried using computed instead of get, but even props.data has updated value, view did not re-render.
Why does this happen? And how can I prevent from view crashing?
Datatable.vue (using get to update value)
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[]
  data: TData[],
  itemsPerPage?: number | undefined,
  showPagination?: boolean | undefined,
}>(), {
  showPagination: false
})

const table = useVueTable({
  get data() { return props.data },
})

Datatable.vue (using computed to update value)

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[]
  data: TData[],
  itemsPerPage?: number | undefined,
  showPagination?: boolean | undefined,
}>(), {
  showPagination: false
})


const data = computed(() => { 
  console.log('props.data :', props.data ) // props.data has updated value, but view did not re-render
  return props.data 
})

const table = useVueTable({
  data:data,

})

myPage.vue
// on template
<DataTable :columns="columnsData" :data="list?.results ?? []"></DataTable>

// initialize
const list = ref({results: []})

// update value when success calling API
list.value = res.data


If I directly return empty array or object data, It won't crash : get data() { return []}. But if I pass empty array data from parent, It also crashed after several tries.

I think this is the issue of tanstack table #5687. View crashing problem solved after updating version from 8.19.3 to 8.20.5.
